# Set subscript and superscript font size to 10pt?

Tags: fontsize

I am using

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
```

And my subscripts/superscripts come out closer to 8pt font (measured by Adobe Acrobat).

How can I globally set these sub/superscript fonts to 10pt?

Comment: `\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{10}{7}`

Comment: For text: `\makeatletter\DeclareRobustCommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@xpt\@xiipt}\makeatother`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not “closer” to 8pt, they *are* 8pt.

The standard declarations are

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{5}{5}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{7}{7}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{8}{8}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{7}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xviipt}{\@xviipt}{\@xiipt}{\@xpt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xiipt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxvpt}{\@xxvpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xviipt}
```

The command `\DeclareMathSizes` takes as first argument the point size to deal with and next the three values for text/display style, script style and scriptscript style.

For historical reasons, sizes larger than 9 are written in symbolic form and, for instance, `\@xivpt` doesn't mean 14, but rather 14.4. But `\@xpt` is 10 and `\@xiipt` is 12.

Thus you can add to your document

```
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{10}{7}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{10}{7}

\begin{document}

$a^n+b_{m_{2}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With

```
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{9}{7}
```

you'd get

[image]

Take your pick. I'd go with the standard 8pt or with 9pt, as 10pt seems really too big.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! Though I wonder what it cost you to venture into the wilderness of LaTeX and return with this arcane knowledge... In the end, it turns out my graduate school doesn't actually care about sizes of sub/superscripts for dissertations, even though the guidelines state they must be 10pt minimum.